# probability of unbalanced dice

Tags: probability

An unbalanced die (with $6$ faces, numbered from $1$ to $6$) is thrown. The probability that the face value is odd is $90$% of the probability that the face value is even. The probability of getting any even numbered face is the same.

If the probability that the face is even given that it is greater than $3$ is $0.75$, what is the probability that the face valued exceeds $3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything here can be expressed in terms of the probability $p$ that a particular even-numbered face comes up: $\Pr(\text{even})=3p$, and $\Pr(\text{odd})=0.9\cdot\Pr(\text{even})=2.7p$. Of course

$$\Pr(\text{even})+\Pr(\text{odd})=1\;,$$

so you can solve for $p$. Let $A$ be the event that the die comes up $4,5$, or $6$, and let $B$ be the event that it comes up $4$ or $6$. You’re told that $\Pr(B\mid A)=\frac34$, you know that $\Pr(B)=2p$, and you should easily be able to see what $\Pr(A\mid B)$ is just by thinking about the two events. Now use [Bayes’ theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_and_interpretation) to find $\Pr(A)$.